# Inception adding new layers

Tags: tensorflow, pre-trained-model

I want to retrain the inception model with 1003 classes where the first 1000 classes are same as imagenet(inception model). So I took with inception model and extracted the final layer weights and added 3 more columns to it. I popped the final layer created another layer with 1003 classes and with the weights I have changed, as the weights of first 1000 classes remains same as inception but while training the accuracy is starting from 0 which I didn't expect. What is going wrong?

this is my code

```
base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
m = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=True)
a=m.layers[312].get_weights()
k=np.random.normal(size=[2048,3])
k=k/3
l=np.random.normal(size=[3])
l=l/3
a[0]=np.concatenate((a[0],k),axis=1)
a[1]=np.concatenate((a[1],l),axis=0)

x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)

predictions = Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax')(x) 
model = Model(input=base_model.input, output=predictions)
model.layers[312].set_weights(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to do some transfer learning (i.e. using the inception v3 model to classify a different set of images than it was originally trained to do). There is a great tutorial on this subject here
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#0

Basically all you have to do is put your training images into folders named by each class (you would have 1003 folders) and run the retrain.py script (included in the tutorial). You want to make sure that retrain.py is run on the new image folders.